# Google AD historical report COLUMNS_NOT_SUPPORTED_FOR_REQUESTED_DIMENSIONS

Tags: python-3.6, google-ads-api

I have python script to download the google ad historical report through the API.
I am having below as report job

```
{
      'reportQuery': {
          'dimensions': [
                         'DATE',
                         'MOBILE_APP_NAME',
                         'ADVERTISER_NAME',
                         'ADVERTISER_ID',
                         'AD_UNIT_ID',
                         'AD_UNIT_NAME',
                         'LINE_ITEM_NAME',
                         'LINE_ITEM_ID',
                         'LINE_ITEM_TYPE',
                         'CREATIVE_TYPE',
                         'CREATIVE_NAME',
                         'CREATIVE_ID',
                         'MOBILE_DEVICE_NAME'
                         'PLACEMENT_NAME',
                         'PLACEMENT_ID'
                         ],
          'dimensionAttributes': [
                                  'AD_UNIT_CODE',
                                  'LINE_ITEM_PRIORITY'
                                  'CREATIVE_CLICK_THROUGH_URL'
                                    'ADVERTISER_EXTERNAL_ID'
                                  ],
          'columns': [
                     'AD_SERVER_IMPRESSIONS',
                     'AD_SERVER_CLICKS',
                      'AD_SERVER_CTR',
                      'AD_EXCHANGE_IMPRESSIONS',
                      'AD_SERVER_CPM_AND_CPC_REVENUE',
                      'AD_SERVER_WITHOUT_CPD_AVERAGE_ECPM'
          ],
          'dateRangeType': 'CUSTOM_DATE',
          'startDate': start_date,
          'endDate': end_date
      }
  }
```

I am getting below error

```
Failed to generate report. Error was: [ReportError.COLUMNS_NOT_SUPPORTED_FOR_REQUESTED_DIMENSIONS @ columns; trigger:'AD_EXCHANGE_IMPRESSIONS'
```

I am not sure which dimension need to include for AD_EXCHANGE_IMPRESSIONS. When I generate report with same fields in UI it works fine without errors